# ArcGIS JavaScript API Geodatabase

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am looking to use the ArcGIS JavaScript API for my website, but I do not want to buy a overly priced ArcServer license. I have an ArcGIS Desktop license, so can I use the ArcGIS Javascript API with a Geodatabase as my back end? If so How?

Comment: If you're OK with a "Developer Plan" instead of an ArcGIS Server license, you might want to look at https://developers.arcgis.com/plans/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can not, sorry. If you want to publish you maps/layers/etc, you need to use ArcServer.

However, if using ArcGIS is not crucial for you, you might want to take a look at other free open source solutions like Mapbox, for example. Depending on what exactly you need to achieve and how much extra coding work you are willing to do, Mapbox may be even better solution for you. From my own experience, it has a nice, easy to follow API with a bunch of examples, which allow you to start developing right away (assuming you have some experience with JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS JavaScript API is used to access and manipulate Services (i.e. data and functionality) published (i.e. made available) via ArcGIS Server. There are many sites that make available ArcGIS Services to the general public and you will be able to access these via the ArcGIS JavaScript API. However, if you want to access your own data, you must publish it somewhere. Esri Online provides some ability to upload small datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You could publish your data to AGOL if it fits the Public License constraints - 1000 features I believe?

If you're ambitious, you could create your own [Geoserver](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/index.html) to host your data. You will need a way to get your data from ArcSDE to PostGIS database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArcGis Developer, here you can publish your maps on ArcGis Online
Check this link [ArcGis Developer](https://developers.arcgis.com/)